Jhipster managing password in application.prod.yml
I have a codepipeline and codebuild workflow that detects github push, builds docker image and pushes to ECR and then pushes this image into my elastic beanstalk environment.
But what it the handlest way to manage the db password e.g.
spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: false
    livereload:
      enabled: false
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx.amazonaws.com/myApp?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: <?>
    password: <?>


You can override the database password with an environment variable named SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD.

indeed I forgot this convention.. thank you
